# win32com.client Outlook automation with permission error

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

Trying to download files from emails in Outlook, as I tried to save them the following error appeared (error code is translated may be different in English):

```
An exception occurred: com_error
(-2147352567, 'Exception.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Cannot save attachment. You do not have the proper permissions to perform this operation.', None, 0, -2147024891), None)
   File "C:\Users\jec\OneDrive - XP Investimentos\Financeiro\X - Teste\Automações\500000\Automation.py", line 17, in <module>
     pdf.SaveAsFile(str(pdf))
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Unable to save attachment. You do not have the proper permissions to perform this operation.', None, 0, -2147024891), None)
```

My code is:

```
import win32com.client as client # python -m pip install --upgrade pywin32
import datetime as datetime
import pandas as pd

## Connect in outlook
outlook = client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamesPace('MAPI')
account = outlook.Folders['financeiro@manchesterinvest.com.br'] # Set the account
inbox = account.Folders['INVESTIMENTO CONTAS A PAGAR'] # Select a folder
   
## Recover the invoice
BHS_email = [message for message in inbox.Items if message.SenderEmailAddress == 'email@test.com.br' and int(pd.to_datetime(message.ReceivedTime, utc = True).strftime("%m")) == int(datetime.date.today().month)] # Only recovers the e-mail from the month (!!!! - CAN RECOVER THE EMAILS FROM THE SAME MONTH IN OTHER YEARS - !!!!)

for message in BHS_email:
    attachment = message.Attachments

    for pdf in attachment:
        pdf.SaveAsFile(str(pdf))
```

Can I override this problem?

Tried to download PDFs from Outlook application with Python, resulted in an error message: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exceção.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Não é possível salvar o anexo. Você não possui a permissão adequada para executar esta operação.', None, 0, -2147024891), None)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting an `Attachment` object to a string, which retrieves it default property - `FileName`. You need to pass the full path to `Attachment.SaveAsFile`, e.g.,

```
pdf.SaveAsFile("c:\temp\" + pdf.FileName)
```